# "An error occurred with the `activeEnergyQuery`. The error was: Authorization not determined."

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm using Apple's demo HealthKit app called ActivityRings. I have set up the bundle identifiers and entitlements correctly. The iOS app and Watch Extension are working and it's recording data seemingly ok. It should be ok as I haven't touched any code.

However console log says, "An error occurred with the `activeEnergyQuery`. The error was: Authorization not determined."

As you can see in the reporting query and handler assignment Apple has written to print for this error.

I'd like to know what this is for. Is there broken functionality?

```
// Create a query to report new Active Energy Burned samples to our app.
    let activeEnergyQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: activeEnergyType, predicate: predicate, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("An error occurred with the `activeEnergyQuery`. The error was: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        // NOTE: `deletedObjects` are not considered in the handler as there is no way to delete samples from the watch during a workout.
        guard let activeEnergySamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }
        sampleHandler(activeEnergySamples)
    }

    // Assign the same handler to process future samples generated while the query is still active.
    activeEnergyQuery.updateHandler = { query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("An error occurred with the `activeEnergyQuery`. The error was: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        // NOTE: `deletedObjects` are not considered in the handler as there is no way to delete samples from the watch during a workout.
        guard let activeEnergySamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }
        sampleHandler(activeEnergySamples)
    }

    currentQuery = activeEnergyQuery
    healthStore.executeQuery(activeEnergyQuery)
}

func endWorkoutOnDate(endDate: NSDate) {
    workoutEndDate = endDate

    workoutButton.setTitle("Begin Workout")
    activeEnergyBurnedLabel.setText("0.0")

    if let query = currentQuery {
        healthStore.stopQuery(query)
    }

    saveWorkout()
}
```

requestAuthorizationToShareTypes function

```
override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user.
    super.willActivate()

    // Only proceed if health data is available.
    guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else { return }

    // We need to be able to write workouts, so they display as a standalone workout in the Activity app on iPhone.
    // We also need to be able to write Active Energy Burned to write samples to HealthKit to later associating with our app.
    let typesToShare = Set([
        HKObjectType.workoutType(),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!])

    let typesToRead = Set([
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!])

    healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(typesToShare, readTypes: typesToRead) { success, error in
        if let error = error where !success {
            print("You didn't allow HealthKit to access these read/write data types. In your app, try to handle this error gracefully when a user decides not to provide access. The error was: \(error.localizedDescription). If you're using a simulator, try it on a device.")
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let healthStore: HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

func applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
    healthStore.handleAuthorizationForExtensionWithCompletion { success, error in
        if let error = error where !success {
            print("You didn't allow HealthKit to access these read/write data types. In your app, try to handle this error gracefully when a user decides not to provide access. The error was: \(error.localizedDescription). If you're using a simulator, try it on a device.")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you setup your iOS app to handle the healthkit authorization from your watch app? When you request permission to use healthkit types from your Apple Watch, a permission dialog shows up on your iOS app. But, you need to tell your iOS app that you are expecting your apple watch to request it. You do this with the following code in your AppDelegate file:

```
func applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    healthStore.handleAuthorizationForExtensionWithCompletion { (success, error) -> Void in
        //...
    }
}
```

Note that data can get sent directly from the watch's sensors (like heart rate and calories burned) to healthkit without needing permission from your app. It sounds like your permission errors are because you are trying to read the data (which you don't have permission to do yet).

Comment: Yes. In fact, Apple already set it up. Data is being sent and recorded. I updated my question to include the AppDelegate so you could see Apple's code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to request authorization to read and write active energy samples. Until the user has chosen whether to authorize your app, authorization will be "not determined". See the [HKHealthStore documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:) for more information about requesting authorization with `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:`.

Comment: Ok That's easy. So all it means is Apple didn't write it in the demo? Because I've been getting all my data fine. If I need to request auth why have I been getting my data? Have you seen this demo?

Comment: it seems Apple already has requestAuthorizationToShareTypes in InterfaceController.swift. I edited my question and pasted it at the bottom. So I'm still not sure why I'm seeing that error in the console even though all data seems to be syncing properly to the Activity app and Health app.